# Moved NS to CloudFlare error NS_BINDING_ABORTED - Headers missing

Tags: cloudflare, node-js, react-js

I’m configuring CloudFlare for the first time. I have a node.js application running on Digital Ocean providing API's. My Front End react app is hosted with Netlify on a different domain and was working, but when I changed the Name Server to CloudFlare, the Front End stopped working.
In CF I can see the records imported.
On Front End, using developer tools I can see error on the ajax calls ‘NS_BINDING_ABORTED’

I noticed within CloudFlare dashboard, when Proxy Status is switched off the Front-end works. It seems that when Proxied, the headers ‘Orgin’ and ‘Referer’ is missing and I cannot see why CF is removing them.

Before incorporating Cloudflare the Front-Ends / server worked over HTTPS.
I have selected FULL under the Cloudflare SSL/TLS tab
I have not set Digital Ocean’s firewalls to block any incoming IP addresses.

I don't think its related to CORS because I cant see CORS error, I think Cloudflare are removing the required headers.
After some time researching this problem unfortunately, I have not been able to solve. Has anyone else experienced this issue?

Comment: What are those headers used for? The referrer is often used for tracking purposes, but I've never seen it break functionality when it is missing. I've never seen the "origin" header set at all by any browser.

Comment: I have a number of Front Ends. As I understand it, when the browser makes an API call, the Origin gets sent to the API by default. Then the API determines which front end is making the request by checking the Origin.
If Cloudfront is blocking the Origin, then the call will fail.